# fromJust Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having problems with converting  a list of Maybes to a list of Strings.

My list looks something like this:  [Nothing, Just 3, Just 9, Nothing, Nothing].

I want to replace all the Nothing's with dots ('.') and all the Just Int's with "Int".

My solution so far does not work.

```
 [if c == Nothing then c = '.' else show (fromJust c) | c <- [Nothing, Just 3.... etc] ]
```

I get this error message: parse error on input `='

I'm guessing I cant just give c the value of '.' like in Java or other languages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nitpick on nomenclature, but this is an important thing in Haskell: the kinds of types. `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`, so there can never be a "list of `Maybe`s", only lists of `Maybe a` for some `a`. Your example `[Nothing, Just 3, Just 9, Nothing, Nothing]` would be `Num a => [Maybe a]`, or perhaps `[Int]`. But this has little to do with your problem.

Comment: Also, if you like, you could replace the Nothings with nothing using catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]  from Data.Maybe. It would leave you with just the Ints, nothing else. It's not what you're after, but it might be what someone else who find your question is after.

Answer (score 8):

use `maybe` from Data.Maybe

```
import Data.Maybe

test = [Nothing, Just 3, Just 9, Nothing, Nothing]

f :: Show a => [Maybe a] -> [String]
f = map (maybe "." show)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the list comprehension to *modify* elements in the list by doing `c='.'`. This is Haskell, so you never modify anything! (Well, except `STRef` or `IORef`, but let's leave that out).

```
[if c == Nothing then "." else show (fromJust c) | c <- [Nothing, Just 3.... etc] ]
```

does the trick: you don't have to specify that you want to replace `c` with `"."`, that's already implied by the use of the list comprehension itself. You just need to give that as the output value of the `if` statement.

(Note that I replaced `'.'` with `"."`, this is of course necessary because all elements of the output list must have the same type. `show (fromJust c)` necessarily has type `String`, so we can't just put `Char`s like `'.'` into the same list.)

But the alternative mentioned by Satvik and MathematicalOrchid is better. In Haskell, you generally try to avoid explicit `if` statements and suchlike if there's an alternative with higher-order functions from the standard libraries, like the `maybe` function. If writing explicit decisions yourself, you should prefer pattern matching over `if`, like

```
[ case c of
     Nothing -> "."
     Just number -> show number
 | c <- [Nothing, Just 3.... etc] ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

```
[if c == Nothing then '.' else show (fromJust c) | c <- [Nothing, Just 3.... etc] ]
```

You don't need to write the `c =` part; just say what to return.

However, the thing you probably want here is the `maybe` function. It takes a value to replace `Nothing` with, and a function to apply when it's `Just`. In your case,

```
[maybe "." show c | c <- [...whatever...] ]
```

should do it. Or you can just do

```
map (maybe "." show) [...whatever...]
```

Whichever tickles your fancy. (IMHO, the latter is clearer.)